# How to identify column in ColumnFilterChanged (devexpress) event

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In this event, I want to identify for which column is this called. I basically want to modify the filterInfo of that column to append % at starting i.e. finally ti becomes {[COLUMNNAME] like "%SearchTerm%"} instead of "SearchTerm%"

here sender is the gridview which i anyways know, and e is basic EventArgs with no extra info.

```
    private void gridView2_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[An old post here](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/6313.aspx) suggests looking into the RowFilter property.

[This](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/56618.aspx) may also be worth a look.